# Get sum of integers from list of strings

Tags: python

```
alist = [["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada-500"],
         ["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"], ["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]

alist_min = [
    min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(',')),
        key=lambda i: int(str.strip(i).split('-')[-1])) for x in alist
]
print(alist_min)
```

Given this script how to get the sum of `alist_min` it will only print the integer so given the result of `[Prada-500, Chloe-200, Bagg-1]` by doing the summation of the list the output would be

```
#total: 701
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` and list comprehension with `split()` function:

```
sum([int(x.split('-')[1]) for x in alist_min])
```

**Full code:**

```
alist = [["Chanel-1000, Dior-2000, Prada-500"],
         ["Chloe-200,Givenchy-400,LV-600"], ["Bag-1,Bagg-2,Baggg-3"]]

alist_min = [
    min(map(str.strip, x[0].split(',')),
        key=lambda i: int(str.strip(i).split('-')[-1])) for x in alist
]
print(alist_min)

print(sum([int(x.split('-')[1]) for x in alist_min]))
```

**Output:**

```
['Prada-500', 'Chloe-200', 'Bag-1']
701
```

**Explanation:**

1. use `split()` to split each string in `alist_min` at character `-`,  into two, the second one has the number.
2. Convert this to an int.
3. Use above logic in list comprehension to generate list of numbers
4. Use `sum()` to take sum of this `list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, along with `map` and `sum`

```py
import re

sum(map(int,(map(lambda x:re.findall('\d+',x)[0], alist_min))))

#output: 701
```